# Horizontally move a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one HTML Page I want in that HTML page I can move some divs horizontally when I click on some link...

Like

```
1       2        3        4        5         6         7
__________________________________________________________________











___________________________________________________________________
```

In between those line the 7 number of divs shows one by one when i click Particular Link & it will come from right side to left side...

```
<div>
 <ul> 
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Typically stack overflow is useful for more specific questions or troubleshooting a specific issue.  It's not really clear what you are trying to do here or what you've tried.  If you post the JavaScript you are trying then you will probably get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery animate for each of your li's and tie them to your target div using a data attribute. When the element is clicked you can animate it left or right and change the opacity by passing those arguments.

**SOURCE**

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

**DOM**

```
<ul>
    <li data-target='your-target-div'>
    ...
</ul>
<div id='your-target-div'></div>
```

**JAVSCRIPT**

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        target = '#'+$(this).data('target');
        $(target).animate({ 
            // ENTER YOUR ANIMATION FOR DIV 
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you might try the jQuery accordian: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might want to 'animate' these divs to do/move/behave in a certain way on a certain action.
Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) it might help.